# How to run JPF in netbeans.?

Tags: java, jpf

I have completed all steps stated below

1. Download and install jpf-core, e.g. from the Mercurial repository
2. -------------- take a break ---------------
3. Download the gov-nasa-jpf-netbeans-runjpf.nbm file from here.
4. From within Netbeans go to Tools->Plugins (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> followed by <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd>)
5. Select the Downloaded tab
6. Click on Add Plugins... (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>)
7. Select the gov-nasa-jpf-netbeans-runjpf.nbm file that was downloaded in step 3
8. Select install
9. Agree to the License agreement
10. Restart Netbeans

Now what i have to do to run  the project?

Comment: Did you try to contact the person that wrote those instructions? What's the source of those instructions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
1. Install netbeans-jpf (see: Installing the NetBeans JPF plugin)
2. Make sure the correct site.properties file is being used for JPF (The default is usually correct)
3. To see which site.properties file is being used:
4. From the NetBeans top menu go to "Tools"->"Options" (Alt+T followed by Alt+O)
5. Select "Miscellaneous" from the top of the Options Window
6. Select the "Java Pathfinder" tab
7. Make sure that "Path to site.properties" is defined properly, uncheck "Use default site.properties location" to change the path
8. From either the "Projects" or "Files" view (on the left of the main NetBeans screen by default,) select the JPF properties file (i.e., a file with a .jpf extension) you would like to run. Right click on this file and select the "Verify..." menu item to run JPF.
9. To view the results, make sure that the "Output" View is open (On the bottom of the main NetBeans screen by default)
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer this official Documentation for the next steps.

https://github.com/javapathfinder/jpf-core/wiki/Run-JPF-with-NetBeans-plugin

Comment: Hi, please considering writing a complete answer, i.e., without needing to refer to links. Links may become inactive and then your answer is not useful!